# Can we call DBMS_JOB.RUN in the background?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, database-administration

I insert some jobs to the job queue with the help of DBMS_JOB.SUBMIT.

Is there anyway that I run them in the background in the next step using DBMS_JOB.RUN?

I don't want the users wait for the DBMS_JOB.RUN.

THANKS!

Comment: Which version of Oracle are you using? [DBMS_JOB is deprecated](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25494/appendix_a.htm#ADMIN11002) so you might be better off looking at DBMS_SCHEDULER.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a Job using [DBMS_SCHEDULER](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/d_sched.htm):

```
BEGIN
  -- Job defined entirely by the CREATE JOB procedure.
  DBMS_SCHEDULER.create_job (
    job_name        => 'YourJobName',
    job_type        => 'PLSQL_BLOCK',
    job_action      => 'BEGIN NULL; /* Your code here*/ END;',
    start_date      => SYSTIMESTAMP, // run the job as soon as possible
    repeat_interval => NULL,         // don't repeat the job
    end_date        => NULL,         // ignore this if its not a repeating job
    enabled         => TRUE,         
    comments        => 'Your comments on and description of the job.');
END;
/
```

You can also change `job_type` to call stored procedures or external executables as well as PL/SQL blocks.

If you want to view your currently running jobs you can use:

```
SELECT JOB_NAME, STATE
FROM   USER_SCHEDULER_JOBS;
```

If you want to [view a log of your jobs](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/schedadmin002.htm#i1007245) then you can use:

```
SELECT *
FROM   USER_SCHEDULER_JOB_LOG
ORDER BY LOG_DATE DESC;
```

and:

```
SELECT *
FROM   USER_SCHEDULER_JOB_RUN_DETAILS
ORDER BY LOG_DATE DESC;
```

Comment: Hi! thanks for your comment. Will it the function (job_action) be executed immediately or it will be put in a job queue?

Comment: will it be in the background?

Comment: It will be put into a job queue but scheduled to be executed as soon as possible from within the queue and, when scheduled like this, I've always experienced that it is started within milliseconds of it entering the queue. Yes, it will be in the background.

Comment: I tested this, and it works, thank you!  I have one more question. Since it is run in the background, I don't get any error message if the function that I call is failed (if an exception is raised). How can we fix this?

Comment: I also have another question. I have a form that call DBMS:SCHEDULER. I asked our DBA to give me the permission to run DBMS:SCHEDULER. This means that all users that are going to work with my new form, should have the same privileges. I don't think that this is a good idea. Is there a way to register the jobs with another user (then we just give this user those privileges)?

Comment: Create a user, grant that user permissions to schedule jobs then create a stored procedure which will create the job and grant the other users `EXECUTE` permissions on that first user's stored procedure.

Comment: It is an asynchronous process - if there is an error then of course you won't get any notification of it as it is in the background. If you want to check for errors then you will have to poll the log tables to see if the job ran successfully or not.